# Toggle button (inside combobox) attach click handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, togglebutton

I am rookie to XAML, WPF (first project ;-)). My goal is to apply a customized combobox declared inside App.xaml. However, if I then use the combobox inside the MainWindow.xaml, I don't know how to attach a click handler to the togglebutton which is anchored inside the combobox. If I add a Click property to the ToggleButton inside the App.xaml, I only succeeded to capture the event if I implement the handler inside App.cs.

What I've tried so far:

- Refer to ToggleButton inside ComboBox element in MainWindow.xaml (I do not have a good intuition of how xaml works at this point ...), which results to some undesired visual effects on the ToggleButton and nothing more.

  ```
  <ComboBox x:Name="someComboBox" 
            Height="23"
            Margin="122,35,1.8,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">

           <ToggleButton Click="toggleHandler_Click" />
  ```
- Fetch ToggleButton from MainWindow.cs and then attach the handler, though the former with the approaches below results to null

  ```
      ToggleButton tBtn = ((ComboBox)someComboBox).FindName("MyToggleButton") as ToggleButton; // null

      ToggleButton tBtn = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(someComboBox, "MyToggleButton"); // null
  ```

Here is the customized combobox inside App.xaml, which I adopted as is

```
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="MyToggleButton"
                                          Grid.Column="2"
                                          ClickMode="Press"
                                          Focusable="false"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>

                            <ContentPresenter Margin="3,3,23,3" 
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                              ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                              x:Name="ContentSite"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                            <TextBox Style="{x:Null}" 
                                     x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                                     Margin="3,3,23,3" 
                                     Background="Transparent"
                                     Focusable="True"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                                     Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                     Visibility="Hidden" />

                            <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                                <Grid MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="White" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderDarkMainBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0" />
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" IsItemsHost="True" TextBlock.Foreground="Black" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ContentSite" Value="Hidden" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: When you run the app and click on the button inside of your `ComboBox` do you get any error?

Comment: No, I don't get any error. Just don't know what is the best practice for capturing the event. There is no problem of handling the click event in App.cs, if I add a Click property to the ToggleButton inside the App.xaml. Still I want to handle the event in the context of MainWindow.

Answer (score -1):

With your first block of XAML, you are added a ToggleButton as a child of the ComboBox. So you can loop all the items in this way:

```
foreach(ToggleButton btn in someComboBox.Items)
{
   btn.Click += event_handler;
}
```

But I don't understand what you need exactly! :-)

Comment: Tried your suggestion and got an 'InvalidCastException' on 'btn'. Also when I navigate the members of 'someComboBox' object, I just cannot spot the ToggleButton.